# Monodevelop, how to set locale programatically

Tags: localization, monodevelop, gtk#

In my gtk# solution in monodevelop 2.6 i have translation project. When i start my application with `LANGUAGE=lang mono application.exe` application is translated.

But, i wanna set locale programatically. 
How to do that?

I tried to find solution, but with no success :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Gtk.Global.SetLocale` method which will have the same effect as setting `LC_ALL`.